# Spring Tool Swite no me deja crear archivo .sql

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, jdbc

estoy intentando meter a mi web service del eclipse, un archivo sql. 
Cuando intento hacerlo el prográma no  me da la opción.

Estas son las dependencias que he probado a usar en mi Pom:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este el problema, el sql no me deja leerlo y me manda abrirlo con una app del ordenador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas grácias a quien consiga solucionarlo.

Comment: Vale..me he dado cuenta que el problema solo lo oscasiona Spring Tool Swite 4, en eclipse se detecta

Comment: Botón derecho en el archivo, Open with y selecciona Internal Editor. PD: No es Swite sino Suite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por algún motivo STS (eclipse con las extensiones de  Spring), tendrá asociado *mal* el editor de los ficheros sql. Puedes arreglarlo seleccionando otro editor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si, era eso XD, aunque me sigue sin aparecer ese editor, al final me he decantado por usar notepad ++. Grácias

Comment: Puedes instalar alguna extensión para tenerlo, o usar el "Text Editor"